# Free $p$-group of nilpotency class $4$

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

I was reading through the article [Words and characters in finite $p$-groups](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.5395v3.pdf), and I got stuck on their presentation of the free $p$-group of nilpotency class $4$ as $G = 1 + J$ where $J = I/I^4$ and $I$ is the ideal generated by $X, Y$ in the algebra of polynomials in the non-commuting indeterminates $X, Y$ with coefficents from $\mathbb{F}_p$.

No matter how I think about that construction, I can’t understand how $G$ is supposed to be a group, and how $1+J$ is even defined (as $I / I^4$ is an independent ring).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It is a group under multiplication

Comment: There is no free 4-step nilpotent $p$-group. You need to fix the exponent too, as they do in the article you quote. (And you also need to specify the number of generators; you seem to mean 2)

Comment: Yes, the idea was for a fixed $p$, sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: It's still unclear. For a fixed $p$, there is no free 4-step nilpotent $p$-group on 2 generators.

Comment: This is p7 of your link. They say "free exponent $p$...". It means it's free **among $p$-groups in which there is no element of order $p^2$**.

Comment: Besides, they use a nonstandard convention for the nilpotency class. It is more common to define the central series as with $G^1=1$, $G^{i+1}=[G,G^i]$ and say that $G$ is $c$-step nilpotent if $G^{c+1}=1$. So $0$-step nilpotent means trivial, 1-step nilpotent means abelian, 2-step nilpotent means that the derived subgroup is contained in the center, and here you're considering the free exponent $p$ 3-step nilpotent group on some number of generators. **Edit** I double checked: they use 2-step nilpotent in the usual meaning. So free 4-step should be when $J=I/I^5$ and not $I/I^4$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R$ be a ring and let $I$ be a two-sided ideal of $R$.
Given an exponent $n ≥ 1$, we can consider the ideal $I^n$ of $R$ and form the quotient ring $R / I^n$.
In this quotient ring, we have the two-sided ideal $I / I^n$.
All elements of $I / I^n$ are nilpotent in $R / I^n$.

Let us recall the following observation about nilpotent elements in a ring:

> **Observation (geometric series).**
> Let $S$ be a ring and let $x$ be a nilpotent element of $S$.
> The element $1 - x$ is invertible in $S$, with inverse given by
> $$
>   (1 - x)^{-1} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \dotsb = \sum_{n = 0}^∞ x^n \,.
> $$
> Similarly, the element $1 + s$ is invertible with inverse given by
> $$
>   (1 + x)^{-1} = 1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + \dotsb = \sum_{n = 0}^∞ (-1)^n x^n \,.
>   \tag{$\ast$}
> $$

This observation has a direct consequence:

> **Corollary.**
> Let $S$ be a ring.
> Let $J$ be an additive subgroup of $S$ closed under multiplication (a “non-unital subring”) and consisting of nilpotent elements.
> The set $1 + J = \{1 + x \mid x ∈ J\}$ is a subgroup of $S^×$ (the group of invertible elements of $S$).
>
> *Proof.*
> Any element $x$ of $J$ is nilpotent in $S$, whence $1 + x$ is invertible in $S$.
> In other words, $1 + J$ is contained in $S^×$.
> The neutral element of $S^\times$ is $1$, which is contained in $1 + J$ because $0$ is contained in $J$.
> For any two elements $x$ and $y$ of $J$, we have
> $$
>   (1 + x)(1 + y) = 1 + x + y + xy \,.
> $$
> The term $x + y + xy$ is again contained in $J$, whence $(1 + x)(1 + y)$ is again contained in $1 + J$.
> This shows that $1 + J$ is closed under multiplication.
> For any element $x$ of $J$ the element $\sum_{n = 1}^∞ (-1)^n x^n$ is again contained in $J$, whence the element $(1 + x)^{-1} = 1 + \sum_{n = 1}^∞ (-1)^n x^n$ is again contained in $1 + J$.
> This shows that $1 + J$ is closed under taking inverses.

> **Corollary of the corollary.**
> Let $S$ be a ring and let $J$ be an ideal of $S$ consisting of nilpotent elements.
> Then $1 + J$ is a subgroup of $S^×$.

Going back to the beginning of this post, we find that for the ideal $J ≔ I / I^n$ of $R / I^n$ the set $1 + J$ is a subgroup of $(R / I^n)^×$.
In other words, $1 + J$ becomes a group via the multiplication from $R / I^n$.